# Running an MVC Project on godaddy plesk file io error

Tags: model-view-controller, plesk, host, filezilla

I have an MVC web project that I am trying to host on godaddy using plesk for administration. My hosting settings for my web page is httpdocs\WebApplication18\WebApplication18/

I have pointed my web project to my configuration file inside WebApplication18.

Folder access to my files look like this:

```
Home Directory -> httpdocs -> WebApplication18 -> WebApplication18
                                                  -> views -> home -> Index.cshtml
                                                  -> web.conf
```

I am trying to browse to my index.cshtml page. I have set the root to run at WebApplication18 where
my configuration file is stored.

When I type in my hostname inside my address bar I recieve a file IO error that states:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Security Exception
Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.

Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.]
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet) +0
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(CodeAccessPermission cap, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +36
   System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand() +48
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.get_AppDomainAppPath() +53
   System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.PreApplicationStartCode.StartCore() +119
   System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.PreApplicationStartCode.Start() +39
```

To begin with custom error mode was turned on, which I turned off in ASP.Nets
settings. I also commented out the compiler error in the web.conf file, which
reduced the error to a file io error.

The question I had was how can I point to my web page properly in my hosting settings 
using mvc so that I can render my index.cshtml page using plesk on a godaddy server?

How am I able to fix this error message? I tried changing all of the permissions
lowered the CAS trust level and it makes no difference to the level of control
I have over my web page.

When I do a File Zilla upload sometimes I receive a certificate, but I just ignore 
it and select ok.

Answer (score -1):

This is only permission issue. Please kindly ask your provider to give full permission for you. It will fix your issue.